# How to populate each cell in a data frame with the (column_name*number in the cell) in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

Below is a data frame df.

I need to populate each cell in a data frame with the (column_name*number in the cell) in R.
Starting from column 2 (pizza) i.e. df[1,2]

Input:

```
   Name  pizza coke fries
1   Tom     1   NA    NA
2  Dick    NA    2     1
3 Harry     3   NA     1
4   Don    NA    2    NA
5  John     2   NA     1
```

Expected Output:

```
   Name     pizza                   coke           fries
1   Tom     pizza                   <NA>           <NA>
2  Dick     <NA>                    coke coke      fries
3 Harry     pizza pizza pizza       <NA>           fries
4   Don     <NA>                    coke coke      <NA>
5  John     pizza pizza             <NA>           fries
```

Comment: What output do you expect from `column_name * number in the cell`? What is `HCC_1 * 3`? What about `HCC_2 * NA`? Please provide expected output.

Comment: Edited: Added expected output.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @AMC I need the output from the input above.

Comment: @helios9 Right, but Stack Overflow is a QA site on programming and software development, not a free code writing service.

Comment: @helios9 _I am trying to learn to code._ So are most people on this site, including myself, I'm not sure I understand how that's relevant here. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials or documentation, either.

Comment: _If you do not have anything constructive to add, kindly ignore_ This may come as a surprise to you, but this site has rules and guidelines and conventions.

Comment: @AMC "_This may come as a surprise to you, but this site has rules and guidelines and conventions_" What is with the condescending tone Sir?

Although this is not a "homework question" I found the below link to be slightly related:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

I do concede that as per the suggestions in the link I could frame my questions better. This was my very first question on Stack Overflow.
A great way you've got here to welcome people to the community.
Peace.

Comment: @helios9 To say that it could be framed better might be a tad generous, but I agree. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277139/question-asking-for-you-to-write-code, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason, [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC It's a shame that you read all that but did not bother to read the below. 
See: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

_**Be inclusive and respectful**: **Avoid sarcasm** and be careful with jokes — tone is hard to decipher online. If a situation makes it hard to be friendly, stop participating and **move on.**_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a logical `matrix` based on the non-NA elements in the 'HCC' columns

```
nm1 <- names(df1)[startsWith(names(df1), 'HCC')]
i1 <- !is.na(df1[nm1])
df1[nm1][i1] <- nm1[col(df1[nm1])][i1]
df1
#  ID HCC_1 HCC_2 HCC_3
#1 P1 HCC_1  <NA>  <NA>
#2 P2  <NA> HCC_2 HCC_3
#3 P3 HCC_1  <NA> HCC_3
#4 P4  <NA> HCC_2  <NA>
#5 P5 HCC_1  <NA> HCC_3
```

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset

```
nm2 <- names(df2)[-1]
i2 <- !is.na(df2[nm2])
df2[nm2][i2] <-  trimws(strrep(paste0(nm2[col(df2[nm2])][i2], " "), df2[nm2][i2]))
df2
#   Name             pizza      coke fries
#1   Tom             pizza      <NA>  <NA>
#2  Dick              <NA> coke coke fries
#3 Harry pizza pizza pizza      <NA> fries
#4   Don              <NA> coke coke  <NA>
#5  John       pizza pizza      <NA> fries
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(ID = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"), HCC_1 = c(1L, 
NA, 3L, NA, 6L), HCC_2 = c(NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA), HCC_3 = c(NA, 
1L, 1L, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5"))

df2 <- structure(list(Name = c("Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Don", "John"
 ), pizza = c(1L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L), coke = c(NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA
 ), fries = c(NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: It sure did work.
Trying to understand what exactly you did there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's pretty neat.